# Android: edittext disappearing

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

When soft keyboard appears in adjustResize mode, my edittext disappears. There is relativelayout with custom view stretched on the hole screen size as background and few edittexts over it. In adjustPan mode all works fine but you can't see editetext behind keyboard. All layout settings are hardcoded, there no xml. If i build it without background view all works fine.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
 <com.mypkg.Panel android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/panel"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></com.mypkg.Panel>
  <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/edit1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
   </EditText>
   </RelativeLayout>

class Panel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {...
```

Comment: If your are Using a 240*320 device this thing happens. try another device

Comment: Show us how you built the layout. This would make it easier to get reliable feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Put your whole layout within a `ScrollView`. With a ScrollView your Layout will be scrolled up or is able to scroll up (depending on the device) once the soft keyboard is enabled.

[Edit]

Summary of the comments below this post: Use the layout folders for ldpi, mdpi and hdpi as proposed by [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

[/Edit]

Comment: Could you provide your layout xml file?

Comment: Why did you not create a layout xml file? It is generally the better and easier to maintain solution.

Comment: My view positions depends on screen size. So it easier to manipulate them from code.

Comment: Before I'm going into more detail, did you read [this document](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)?

Comment: Ok i will try to build all in xml

Comment: This worked for me. Before that the my layout would be pushed off screen.

Answer (score 1):

> `<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> </activity>`

Add this line to your AndroidManifest.xml. Worked for me!  :)